# How to mockup the NiFi interface to test ExecuteScript files

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Python script that runs successfully via the ExecuteScripts processes in NiFi's UI.
How can I perform tests on the script without having to use NiFi?

The main issue with running the script from the command line is that I don't have access to the `session` object. Is there a way to artificially create a `session` object and import all the necessary NiFi libraries (i.e. to mock up the NiFi interface)?

Comment: Take a look at source code of nifi, ExecuteScripts test cases.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-scripting-bundle/nifi-scripting-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/script/TestExecuteJython.java

Comment: check: https://github.com/TouK/plumber